# SQL Server Error Log

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

> Application: sqlsqm.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: System.IO.FileLoadException
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Sqm.Launcher.Main(System.String[]).

This always happen every day in the log file. I don't know what is the problem. Could you help me ?

Comment: Did you install the latest service packs, for SQL Server and .NET framework? Also, is that the full context of the problem? Nothing more in the log that could shed some light on the issue?

Comment: Not that anyone is likely to be able to solve this but.. you need to provide a lot more info. Is it running out of memory? Is it in a VM? Did  you run out of disk space? Whats the exact version of SQL? What's the version of the OS? Does the time correlate with anything else in the windows log?